# Meaning of a line from the sitcom "Friends"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

In one of the episodes of *Friends*, Ross who plays the professor, calls a student and has a talk with him saying, he is afraid that he have to fail him because of low mark. The student says, he is in love with Ross. Ross shockingly (I think) replies that brings me in a loop a little.

I have two questions to ask: The first, what did he mean by saying, "that brings me in a loop a little"?
The second, in words how do we say the student’s action was for e.g.: "The student playfully or ridiculously responses."

What is the exact word to define the student reply or action?

Answer (score 1):

"In the loop" usually refers to a circle of interest. For example, if a matter is on a 'need-to-know' basis, those who know about it are said to be "in the loop".

In the context of the sitcom, the student begins by telling Ross that he is "in love" (without specifying who his interest is). Ross replies "that's not my problem". It is only when the student says "I'm in love with *you*" that he says "well that brings me in the loop a little". This is a comedic way of saying that, whereas the student's love interests were originally none of his concern, this second piece of information involves him in it.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclusion. "In the loop" means to be informed about something, he's basically saying "now I understand". That's just my interpretation though. Whatever happens, this is the answer to build on, as it contains important context.

Comment: Astralbee is absolutely right. One definition of ["loop"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loop) is "a select well-informed inner circle that is influential in decision making". Ross's comment is linked to this idea: on finding she's in love with her, that puts him in a position where he's involved in her actions and decisions, i.e. "in the loop" (this phrase isn't normally used in the context of romance, but that's him being humorous). Being in the loop is about more than knowledge.